# Creating the checkbox dynamically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to create a checkbox dynamically using following HTML/JavaScript. Any ideas why it doesn't work?

```
<div id="cb"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cbh = document.getElementById('cb');
    var val = '1';
    var cap = 'Jan';

    var cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.type = 'checkbox';
    cbh.appendChild(cb);
    cb.name = val;
    cb.value = cap;
    cb.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cap));
</script>
```

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You're trying to put a text node inside an input element.

Input elements are empty and can't have children.

```
...
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.type = "checkbox";
checkbox.name = "name";
checkbox.value = "value";
checkbox.id = "id";

var label = document.createElement('label')
label.htmlFor = "id";
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text for label after checkbox'));

container.appendChild(checkbox);
container.appendChild(label);
```

Comment: Note that in some flavors of IE, the checkbox.checked value won't stick unless you set it AFTER the control's been appended to the page.

Comment: I want the checkbox inside the label, but doing label.appendChild(checkbox) doesn't work for me -- it puts the checkbox outside the label. How would you do this?

Answer (score 2):

The last line should read

```
cbh.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cap));
```

Appending the text (label?) to the same container as the checkbox, not the checkbox itself

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function:

```
function changeInputType(oldObj, oTyp, nValue) {
  var newObject = document.createElement('input');
  newObject.type = oTyp;
  if(oldObj.size) newObject.size = oldObj.size;
  if(oldObj.value) newObject.value = nValue;
  if(oldObj.name) newObject.name = oldObj.name;
  if(oldObj.id) newObject.id = oldObj.id;
  if(oldObj.className) newObject.className = oldObj.className;
  oldObj.parentNode.replaceChild(newObject,oldObj);
  return newObject;
}
```

And you do a call like:

```
changeInputType(document.getElementById('DATE_RANGE_VALUE'), 'checkbox', 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   /* worked for me  */
     <div id="divid"> </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var hold = document.getElementById("divid");
         var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
         checkbox.type = "checkbox";
         checkbox.name = "chkbox1";
         checkbox.id = "cbid";
         var label = document.createElement('label');
         var tn = document.createTextNode("Not A RoBot");
         label.htmlFor="cbid";
         label.appendChild(tn); 
         hold.appendChild(label);
         hold.appendChild(checkbox);
      </script>
```

Comment: the "value"  attribute in a checkbox is kinda vague.  the link give a little info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox

Comment: This is a code only answer, Can you explain the code? How does it differ from existing answers?