# html: Dynamic add checkbox failure?

Tags: html, dynamic, checkbox, checkboxlist

I want to make a webpage that can dynamically add checkbox.

The follows is my code. It can add label, however, it can't add checkbox. I don't know the reason?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script text="text/javascript">
        function dynamicAdd(){
            var name = document.getElementById("addName");
            var checkbox= document.createElement(name.value);
            checkbox.type="checkbox";
            checkbox.name=name.value;
            checkbox.value=name.value;
            checkbox.id=name.value;

                var label = document.createElement("label");
                label.htmlFor="id";
                label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("text for label after checkbox"));

                var container = document.getElementById("checklist");
                container.appendChild(checkbox);
                container.appendChild(label);


            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form  id="checklist">
        <input type="checkbox"  value="windows">Windows Clean</input><br>
        <input type="checkbox"  value="floor">Floor Clean</input><br>

    </form>
        <input type="text" id="addName" size="25" maxlength="50" value="elevator"><br>
        <Button type="button" onclick="dynamicAdd()" name="add">AddOption</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.createElement(name.value);
```

Is **false**, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866239/creating-the-checkbox-dynamically-using-javascript) (@Quentin).

*Text extract from the link*

```
...
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.type = "checkbox";
checkbox.name = "name";
checkbox.value = "value";
checkbox.id = "id";

var label = document.createElement('label')
label.htmlFor = "id";
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text for label after checkbox'));

container.appendChild(checkbox);
container.appendChild(label);
```