# create checkboxes dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, checkbox

I'm trying to create check boxes dynamically. But I have no idea what is the wrong with this code. Somebody please help. Comment if you need more details.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
  console.log(json);
  console.log(json.items.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < json.items.length; i++) {

    console.log(json.items[i].name);

    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = "name" + json.items[i].name;
    checkbox.value = "value";
    checkbox.id = "id" + i;
  }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: You are not adding them to document

Comment: "No idea what's wrong with the code" - what have you tried / how exactly is it failing?

Comment: Hmm... is there any error that you are facing? Or it's just that the checkboxes are not appearing? You probably will need to append the checkboxes created to existing elements on the page such as the body? or some div? Perhaps you can provide more information about what problem are you actually facing?

Comment: Also suggest doing more research before asking a new question - google for "create checkboxes dynamically in Javascript" turns up several examples on SO that you could have looked at for ideas first

Comment: Before I add checkbox part, I could print `console.log(json.items[i].name);`. But after adding checkbox, that log also did not appear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating the checkbox dynamically using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866239/creating-the-checkbox-dynamically-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks all for the help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never seem to be appending those dynamically created checkboxes to your DOM, so this `checkbox` variable that you create inside the loop simply gets garbage collected. If you want those checkboxes to appear somewhere make sure that you are actually adding them to the DOM:

```
document.body.appendChild(checkbox);
```

Of course instead of simply appending them to the `body` of the DOM you might want to append them to some specific element in which case you might need to get this element first:

```
var someDiv = document.getElementById('someId');
someDiv.appendChild(checkbox);
```

or if you are using jQuery:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.items.length; i++) {
    $('<input />', {
        type : 'checkbox',
        id: 'id' + i,
        name: 'name' + json.items[i].name,
        value: 'value'
    })
    .appendTo("#someId"); 
}
```

where you obviously have the corresponding container to harbor those newly added elements:

```
<div id="someId"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just what Darin said,

you need to append a dynamically created element to the DOM. So in your case

```
        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        console.log(json); 
        console.log(json.items.length);

        for(var i=0;i<json.items.length;i++){

        console.log(json.items[i].name);

        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = "checkbox";
        checkbox.name = "name"+json.items[i].name;
        checkbox.value = "value";
        checkbox.id = "id"+i;   
        document.body.appendChild(checkbox);
        }
    });
```

OR You can create a div in your HTML sheet, and append your checkboxes to that, so it would be something like ..

```
   var div = document.getElementById('div');
   for(var i=0;i<json.items.length;i++){

    console.log(json.items[i].name);

    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = "name"+json.items[i].name;
    checkbox.value = "value";
    checkbox.id = "id"+i;   
    div.appendChild(checkbox);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the checkbox in some html container. say you have a div with id `append` like below,

```
<div id="append" name="append">Append here</div>
```

and your dynamically created checkbox added to that div.

**js:**

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
      console.log(json);
      console.log(json.items.length);

      for (var i = 0; i < json.items.length; i++) {

            var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = "name" + json.items[i].name;
            checkbox.value = "value";
            checkbox.id = "id" + i;
            document.getElementById( 'append' ).appendChild( checkbox);

      }
});
```