# How to fill checkbox with data in a config file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, config

I would like to be able to fill a list of checkbox with **datas from a config file**.

In fact, if my checkbox is made to choose a Sport, in my config file I have something like this in JSON :

`sports: ["Tennis", "Rugby", "Soccer"]`

I would like my checkbox to be adaptative, means that the number of inputs is mapped on the length of the table in the JSON file.

Thank you very much for your help !

**Edit :**

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="form-check">
    <label for="editSports">Pick your sport(s)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="editSports" name ="editSports">
    </input>
</div>
```

And I am wondering how to fill it with Javascript, I guess I'll have to do something like this :

```
ddn = $("#editSharedFolders");
config.sports.forEach(sport=> {
        ddn.append($('<checkbox>', {value: sport, text: sport})); //This line is the problem I guess
});
```

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work as expected?

Comment: Just edited, I try what's above but when I launch I haven't any input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a clean vanilla js approach.

It iterates over your constants and checks if the id exists for any element. If so it adds each element to the select. This should get you in the right direction. If you have further questions feel free to ask them.

My personal opinion is to avoid jQuery as much as possible if its not needed. So I'd always prefer a vanilla javascipt solution over jQuery.

Edit: To get checkboxes for each element in the array, I used this implementation: [Creating the checkbox dynamically using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866239/creating-the-checkbox-dynamically-using-javascript)

```js
let constants = {sports: ["Tennis", "Rugby", "Soccer", "Basketball"]}
for (type in constants){
    
    constants[type].forEach(function(element){
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = element;
    checkbox.value = element;
    checkbox.id = element;
    
    var label = document.createElement('label')
    label.htmlFor = element;
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(element));
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(checkbox);
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(label);
    })
   }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you this help, however would this work with a checkbox input, as I have to be able to pick multiple sports ?

Comment: That's perfect ! Thank you very much

Comment: Please mark my answer as the accepted one @MaxG so people can find a working solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this below in your script :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sports = ["Tennis", "Rugby", "Soccer"]
    for (i = 0; i < sports.length; i++) { 
            $("#checkbox_container").append ( "<label for='check_"+ i +"'>" + sports[i] + "</label><input id='check_" + i + "' type='checkbox' value='"+sports[i]+"'/><br/>" );
    }
});

</script>
```

And in your html do this :

```
<body>
<div id="checkbox_container">
</div>
</body>
```